# PHP framework for this specific use case

Tags: php, looking-for-a-script

I have to develop a site like `http://www.monster.com` with these standard set of features:

- Users should be able to register, login, create their profile, upload their resume and photo.
- Site Admin(s) should be able to post jobs. All the users whose profile matches the posted jobs should be notified of the new job.

I have one year experience in PHP, but haven't used any frameworks (CMS) up till now. I looked at WordPress, Laravel, CakePHP, Drupal, Joomla, etc. but couldn't decide which one to choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use WordPress for these specific features (all you mention are already developed in this CMS or can be easily implemented with a plugin or some basic knowledge of PHP).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Zistoloen. I'm new to WordPress. I know only how to use it but don't know how to customize it. Can you please suggest me how to get started.

Comment: It's hard to explain you how to customize it. Now, you know you can use WordPress for your website, so [get's started](http://codex.wordpress.org/Getting_Started_with_WordPress).